# Sensible Doctrine Expression and Zend_Auth setCredentialTreatment()

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework, doctrine

How to create reasonable expression to store password in database using `Doctrine` and `Zend_Auth::setCredentialTreatment()`?

I don't want to use `md5()` and the code must be portable, and with salt.

I would call this not easy one to guess:

`setCredentialTreatment("SHA1(CONCAT(username, SHA1(CONCAT(username, ?)))");`

but it is not portable to all databases.

Seems that [Doctrine_Expression](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/hu/component-overview:record:using-expression-values) has only `md5` expression portability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not write your own `Zend_Auth_Adapter`?